# Is it possible to draw Highcharts PlotBand and/or PlotLines lower/higher then xAxis/top tick?

Tags: highcharts

Is there any options to make xAxis band/line to start lower then xAxis itself and extends higher then the top of chart area? Or contrariwise stop lets say at the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is no option to reduce or increase the height of the xAxis `plotBands` and `plotLines`, but by using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` you can easily cover the part of them:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var x = this.plotLeft,
                y = this.plotTop,
                width = this.plotSizeX,
                height = 60;


            this.renderer.rect(x, y, width, height)
                .attr({
                    fill: '#fff',
                    zIndex: 0
                }).add()
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7xwsa0tg/

or create custom `plotBands`:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
                x = xAxis.toPixels(1),
                y = this.plotTop,
                width = xAxis.toPixels(3) - xAxis.toPixels(1),
                height = this.plotSizeY - 50;


            this.renderer.rect(x, y, width, height)
                .attr({
                    fill: 'green',
                    zIndex: 0
                }).add()
        }
    }
},
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tmour721/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Comment: Will this approach be working with Boost module and WebGL?
And second, how can I switch this on and off at runtime?

Comment: Hi Dimanoid, Yes, this solution work with the boost module: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ltp843em/. To swich on or off the custom plotBands, you can easliy use some `if` statemant, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fLyjb81m/

Comment: I mean if I have for example 3 bands and need to "switch off" just one I will need to recreate whole chart because the drawing happens at load event, right?

Comment: @Dimanoid, No, you can store somewhere the reference to the custom elementand use `destroy` method only on the element: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#destroy, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k8z92rej/